# Can I enable backorder for b2b cusotmer only in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, b2b

I have a store with a shared catalog. In which, B2b features are enabled. I want to enable the back-order feature only for the b2b customer. How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.